# How syncing data is possible in different instances of a database image running as containers in different nods?

Tags: database, kubernetes, containers

In a scenario where there are multiple containers running multiple instances of a database, when data in one instance is changed, how that change is applied to other instances so the data consistency preserved? it should be taken into consideration that containers may have bee placed in different nodes, so they can't share a common volume.

Comment: Kubernetes does not do anything like that - it only cares about scheduling and running workloads. You would need some sort of clustering-capable database to keep different nodes of itself in sync.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want to know is it common two have more than one instance of database container in the first place? so there would be the need to sync different instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploying database to Kubernetes in high-availability mode is a quite complex task.

To save a lot of time, please consider using [Kubernetes operators](https://enterprisersproject.com/article/2019/2/kubernetes-operators-plain-english). This way you can automate most of complex manual operations. Kubernetes operators allow you to describe desired configuration of an application (or database) in declarative way.

Kubernetes operator in general is a set of additional objects (pods, services, configmaps, secrets, RBAC, custom resources definitions, PV, PVC, ...) responsible to create and maintain complex application lifecycle.

Usually Kubernetes operators related to database applications take care about deploying database cluster of the desired size to Kubernetes and creating all required resources. Also they keep desired number of replicas, implement backup/restore procedures, configure data replication, forward client traffic to a healthy database pod and more.

Most of well-known databases have ready-to-use operators already. You can find some resources below:

Mysql Resources:

- [Introducing the Oracle MySQL Operator for Kubernetes](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/introducing-the-oracle-mysql-operator-for-kubernetes)
- [Oracle MySQL Operator on GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/mysql-operator)
- [Getting started with the MySQL Operator for Kubernetes](https://medium.com/oracledevs/getting-started-with-the-mysql-operator-for-kubernetes-8df48591f592)

Percona Resources:

- [Percona Kubernetes Operator for Percona XtraDB Cluster](https://www.percona.com/doc/kubernetes-operator-for-pxc/index.html)
- [MySQL Operator](https://www.presslabs.com/docs/mysql-operator/)
- [MySQL Operator on Github](https://github.com/presslabs/mysql-operator)

PostgreSQL resources:

- [Crunchy Data PostgreSQL Operator](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator)
- [Postgres Operator](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator)

MongoDB resources:

- [Install the MongoDB Enterprise Kubernetes Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/install-k8s-operator/#install-the-k8s-op-full)

In case you are planning to use different type of database, please check for available operator from DB vendor searching "*DBname kubernetes operator*"

Answer (score 0):

If you are going with normal `deployment` with an application that just uses folder to access data it is advisable to use [Persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), it could be either be `nfs` or several other options  mentioned in the documentation where you mount the same volume inside all different pods having access to same data.

And if you are trying to host a database which is an application with state, it is advisable to use a `statefulset` instead of normal `deployment` when coming to applications like mongodb, mysql, etc.

Here is a how the [statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) works. But there are several online resources that gives you the differences between using a `deployment vs statefulset` for databases. But however, before statefulsets were introduced into k8s many of our database applications were deployed using PVC, it also has lot of overhead.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This is dangerous advice. Running multiple DB servers off the same files on NFS for example is likely not going to work or even lead to data loss.